# Kafka file transfer from ms sql server to s3 bucket?

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, minio

I need to transfer files in SQL Server to Minio.
When a file is written to a table in MS SQL Server, I want to write/transfer it to Minio bucket via Kafka s3 Connector.
Is it possible via Kafka?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.

1. Ingest the data from MS SQL using Kafka Connect (e.g. [JDBC Source connector](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/#starting-table-capture) or [Debezium](https://rmoff.net/2019/11/20/streaming-data-from-sql-server-to-kafka-to-snowflake-with-kafka-connect/) or [other options](http://rmoff.dev/ksny19-no-more-silos))
2. Stream the data to Minion via the S3 sink connector. [This blog](https://blog.minio.io/journaling-kafka-messages-with-s3-connector-and-minio-83651a51045d) suggests that it is compatible. See [this video](https://rmoff.dev/kafka-s3-video) for an example of the connector

For general understanding of Kafka Connect see [this talk](http://rmoff.dev/ksny19-no-more-silos).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to look at the new Polybase features in SQL2022, that should allow you to access S3 from SQL2022 directly, not sure if for your scenario then Kafka is still necessary ?